# pytest - show test module name in output

Tags: python, pytest

How can I show the path to the test function next to the function name when a test fails? What I would like to see:

```
======================FAILURES==========================
_____________path/to/module::function_name______________
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The headline is controlled by the `head_line` property of the `TestReport` class, although beware it's marked experimental, so it's not impossible that it may be renamed or replaced in the next versions. Create a file named `conftest.py` in your project root dir with the contents:

```
import pytest
from _pytest.reports import TestReport


class CustomReport(TestReport):

    @TestReport.head_line.getter
    def head_line(self):
        return f'my headline: {self.nodeid}'


@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    return CustomReport.from_item_and_call(item, call)
```

Example output:

```
$ pytest -v
======================================= test session starts =======================================
...
test_spam.py::test_spam PASSED                                                              [ 20%]
test_spam.py::test_eggs FAILED                                                              [ 40%]
test_spam.py::test_bacon[1] FAILED                                                          [ 60%]
test_spam.py::test_bacon[2] FAILED                                                          [ 80%]
test_spam.py::TestFizz::test_buzz FAILED                                                    [100%]

============================================ FAILURES =============================================
______________________________ my headline: test_spam.py::test_eggs _______________________________

    def test_eggs():
>       assert False
E       assert False

test_spam.py:8: AssertionError
____________________________ my headline: test_spam.py::test_bacon[1] _____________________________

n = 1

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('n', range(1,3))
    def test_bacon(n):
>       assert False
E       assert False

test_spam.py:13: AssertionError
____________________________ my headline: test_spam.py::test_bacon[2] _____________________________

n = 2

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('n', range(1,3))
    def test_bacon(n):
>       assert False
E       assert False

test_spam.py:13: AssertionError
_________________________ my headline: test_spam.py::TestFizz::test_buzz __________________________

self = <test_spam.TestFizz object at 0x7f5e44ba2438>

    def test_buzz(self):
>       assert False
E       assert False

test_spam.py:18: AssertionError
=============================== 4 failed, 1 passed in 0.06 seconds ================================
```